# Не видит класс в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function index()
 {
   $authors = Author::all();
   return view('authors.index', compact('authors'));
 }
```

А пишет ошибку:

> "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Author' not found"

Comment: Вы указали путь к нему? `use ...\...\...\Author`?

Comment: В ошибке говориться, что класс `Author` не найден. Проверьте на самом ли деле в папке `Controllers` хранится `Author`. Если да, проверьте, подключили ли вы его в контроллере, как описано выше. А вообще желательно поместить модели в отдельную папку - `Models`.

Answer (score 1):

вверху контроллера напиши

```
use App;
use App\Authors;
```

Или просто в коде впили слеш

```
public function index()
 {
   $authors = \Author::all();
   return view('authors.index', compact('authors'));
 }
```